# How can I swap characters across a colon?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I am looking to swap characters across a colon such that either side replaces each other.

Example: 
Input

```
1: Hello
2: World
3: I
4: am 
5: Brendan
```

Output:

```
Hello: 1
World: 2
I: 3
am: 4
Brendan: 5
```

I have tried using cut and sed but could not find a correct method.

Comment: Is that input one single line, or 5 lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `awk`

```c
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=": "}{print $2, $1}' file.txt
```

Or sed with that has an `-E` option.

```
sed -E 's/(.+): (.+)/\2: \1/' file.txt
```

Or a slower if not slowest shell solution.

```bsh
while IFS=": " read -r first second; do
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$second" "$first"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: You don’t need the `-E` (or `-r`) option.  Depending on how you interpret the question’s requirement, `s/\(.*\): \(.*\)/\2: \1/` might be good enough.  If you insist on the capture groups being non-null, use the intuitive `s/\(..*\): \(..*\)/\2: \1/` or the visually appealing (but functionally equivalent) `s/\(.*.\): \(.*.\)/\2: \1/`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', thank you for that wonderful comment. I've learned something in this too.

Comment: Note that the characters in the `IFS` variable are not use as a string. If you set it to colon and space, unquoted expansions (and the fields read by `read`)  will be split on colons and on spaces, not on the string `: ` (colon+space).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regardless of the input being one or several lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: ]*"; OFS=":" }{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s: %s ", $i, $(i-1); print _}' file
```